# Mysql server not starting without Xamp or Wampserver, How to Use a Common Database for all

Tags: mysql, xampp, wamp

I have WAMPSERVER and XAMPP installed on my windows. Now for Learning Laravel I installed MYSQL. But the issue is that whenever I try to use the command `~mysql -u root` it shows `ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)`

I tried Starting the MYSQL FROM XAMPP or WAMPSERVER and then the `~mysql -u root` command shows connected successfully.
The issue is that when the MYSQL is started with WAMPSERVER then I can only access the database which I had created using WAMP MYSQL server.

Why does my MYSQL fails to connect, and is there any way to use a common database for XAMP and WAMPSERVER?

Comment: Are you using both `xampp` and `wamp` together? You should use one out of it because `mysql` uses port `3306`, you're using it on wamp, you wont be able to access xampp.

Comment: No I only use either one of them at a time. I tried starting MYSQL before starting WAMP or XAMP. But its Not establishing connection :(

Comment: `mysql` won't work without starting either `xampp` or `wamp`. Once you open `xampp`, you connect `mysql` from it. That's when you will be able to use `mysql` effectively.